# Airflow - Task-Group with Dynamic task - Can't trigger Downstream if one upstream is failed/skipped

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've an Airflow DAG where I've a task_group with a loop inside that generates two dynamic tasks. After the task_group I need to perform other actions. My problem is:
Inside the task_group I've a branching operators that validates if the last task should run or not. In case of one of the two flows are completed with success, I want to continue my process. For that I'm using the trigger_rule one_success. My code:

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='hello_world',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 8, 25),
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup = False,
    concurrency = 1,
) as dag:
    task_a = DummyOperator(task_id="task_a")
    with TaskGroup(group_id='task_group') as my_group:
        my_list = ['a','b']
        for i in my_list:
            task_b = PythonOperator(
                        task_id="task_a_".format(i),
                        python_callable=p_task_1)
            var_to_continue = check_status(i)
            
            is_running = ShortCircuitOperator(
                task_id="is_{}_running".format(i),
                python_callable=lambda x: x in [True],
                op_args=[var_to_continue])

            task_c = PythonOperator(
                task_id="task_a_".format(i),
                python_callable=p_task_2)
            
            task_b >> is_running >> task_c
    task_d = DummyOperator(task_id="task_c",trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS)
    
    task_a >> my_group >> task_d
```

My problem is: if one of the iterations return skipped the task_d is always skipped, even one of the flow return success.

Do you know how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep search, I found the problem.
In fact, by default `ShortCircuitOperator` ignore all the downstream tasks trigger rules, if its value is `False`, it will cut the circuit, which means it will skip all the downstream tasks (its downstream tasks and their downstream tasks and their downstream tasks, ...).

In Airflow 2.3.0, in this [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/20044), they added a new argument `ignore_downstream_trigger_rules` with default value `True` to ignore the downstream trigger rules, but you can stop that by providing a `False` value.

If you are using a version older than 2.3.0, you should replace the operator `ShortCircuitOperator` by another solution, for ex:

```py
def check_condition():
   if not condition: # add your logic
       raise AirflowSkipException()
is_running = PythonOperator(..., python_callable=check_condition)

is_running >> task_c
```